# Programmatically Get Disk Usage Of SPWeb Object In Sharepoint 2010 C#

Tags: sharepoint-2010, diskspace, spweb

I am trying to figure out how to get the disk space used on a SharePoint Site(SPWeb).  I have seen solutions that involve PowerShell or going through all of the libraries and iterating through all of the files to get the total size.

However, given the size of our SharePoint Sites, we can't iterate through all of the files.  Also, we are unable to use PowerShell given the program we are trying to write.

Is there another way to get the disk space of a Sharepoint Site(SPWeb Object)?